# SSRS - Access Denied Only Web Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been trying to fix this for days and any input would be much appreciated.

I have a server running Win Server 2012 R2 hosting IIS (MVC.Net site, IIS 8) and 2 SQL server instances (SQL 2016). One of these instances has Reporting Services installed on it.

Accessing http://localhost/Reports is completely OK and it recognises me as an administrator.

Try what I might however but every time I try and access http://localhost/ReportServer I get an Access Denied error message. I also cannot connect to the Reporting Services instance via Management Studio.

This used to work. Before deploying the MVC site the reporting services worked without issue.. However, everything I read says that IIS and SSRS are no longer interconnected.

- The Service Account has roles on the SQL server and directory permissions
- I have tried with the virtual service account and a domain service account
- I have tried new/different databases
- I have tried installing a new instance of SQL server as a last ditch test, same issue
- Setting an execution account has no impact
- Changing ports has no impact
- Changing virtual directories has no impact

Any help would be very, very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to check SQL Reporting services setup, There should be two urls one for Server and another for report manager. It must be browse from reporting setup. If you are getting the same error from here then your problem is different not related to service setup.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my initial message wasn't clear - 

Web Portal URL (/Reports/ default) runs completely fine and regocnises me as an Admin. Web Service URL (/ReportServer/ default) has access denied error no matter what I try.